# Is it possible to capture optional argument for handlers in Tornado

Tags: python, regex, tornado

I have a URL binded to a handler in Tornado. e.g.

```
(r'/browse/article/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]*)', ArticleHandler),
```

However, the number of arguments is not fixed, such that some will be `/browse/article/blah`, others will be `/browse/article/blah/2`. In other words, the last argument may or may not exist.

Is it still possible to use a single handler to handle this case? If so, how should I formulate the regex string to match all possible cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
(r'/browse/article/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(?:/([0-9]*))?', ArticleHandler),
```

This makes the last segment optional while keeping the capturing parentheses intact, in case they are used for something later.